# Combine indexOf and regexp match in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I need to return position of string that contains `false` within array.

```
[​"2: true", "4: true", ​"7: false", ​"8: true", ​"10: true"]
```

Below code returns new array with position reset, should be `2`.

```
return arrCom.filter(s => s.includes("false"));
```

Comment: Why `.indexOf()`? Why regex? Why `.filter()`? Why `.includes()`?

Comment: I'm trying to learn their mechanics thus taking them into consideration while developing solution.

Comment: `filter` helped me to create split arrays to seperate `true` from `false`. These records got tracked by `include`. `RegExp` was a possibility I took into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a regular expression or `indexOf`. To find the index of the first entry in an array that matches an arbitrary criterion, use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
const index = array.findIndex(entry => entry.includes("false"));
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = ["2: true", "4: true", "7: false", "8: true", "10: true"];
const index = array.findIndex(entry => entry.includes("false"));
console.log(index);
```

If you wanted the entry itself, you'd use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

If there might be multiple matches and you wanted **all** of their indexes, the simplest way would be to use a loop:

```
const indexes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i].includes("false")) {
        indexes.push(i);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = ["2: true", "4: true", "7: false", "8: true", "10: true"];
const indexes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i].includes("false")) {
        indexes.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(index);
```

Comment: I used `indIndex:` before but with no luck. Maybe becasue I didn't reset my cache in browser. Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array of index which contains `false` using `Array.reduce`.
On the following example, third paramter of callback in `Array.reduce` represents the current index.

You can know more about `Array.reduce` on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const input = [ "2: true", "4: true", "7: false", "8: true", "10: true" ];
const output = input.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => {
  if (curV.includes('false')) {
    acc.push(curI);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: `reduce` doesn't make sense for this. The OP is looking for the index of a matching entry. That's **exactly** what `findIndex` is for.

Comment: The result needed here is the index value so there is no need to use `Array.filter`. It's better to use `Array.forEach` or `Array.reduce` and `Array.reduce` is better so I have mentioned that.

Comment: Is that meant as a reply to me? I didn't say anything about `filter`. `reduce` isn't better than what I did mention, `findIndex`. (And separately, unless you're doing functional programming with predefined reusable reducers, `reduce` is almost always unnecessarily complex.)

Comment: I have not used `Array.findIndex` because there can be multiple variables which contains `false`. And `Array.reduce` is good to get all indexes. Of course, if want only one index, `Array.findIndex` is better.